# windows 10 keep restarting

Tags: windows, windows-10, reboot, event-viewer

Last week windows has been restarting 6-7 times every day.

Same message every time:

> El proceso C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe (JOROPEZA) inició el Reinicio del equipo JOROPEZA en nombre del usuario NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM por el siguiente motivo: Sistema operativo: service pack (planeado)
>    Código de motivo: 0x80020010
>    Tipo de apagado: Reinicio
>    Comentario:
>
> The process scvhost.exe start pc reboot with user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for Operative Systeme service pack (planned)

**So what is wrong with service pack doesnt finish the update and need so many restart?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that 0x80020010 indicates your system restarted because of an software update or some update. Keep digging until what updated in your system. Cause that update causes your system to restart. so keep checking your event viewer and probably that update history in windows 10 and check the windows store update page as well. those software do update...and often forgotten as well by most people

Comment: Agreed, an update or install is causing this issue.  Try starting in Safe Mode so that you can investigate without being rebooted, then roll back or uninstall the problem update or program.  Windows Update has a history, Control Panel->Programs and Features has a history.  If you don't see anything that installed immediately before the problem started, scroll back to the day in Event Viewer and you may see something informative.